# Ways to disconnect or connect power cable with a command without physically unplugging it in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, power-management, laptop, battery-charging-threshold

On ubuntu 20.04, I start looking for ways to automate the charging period of a laptop, this means that the power cable stays always plugged in, but the system must effectively internally disconnect or connect it based on the battery percentage. During my search I came across tools like the `upower` command, `udevadm` command, and the `/sys/class/power_supply/` directory. I also find ways to simulate it, but I want that the power to be effectively disconnect or connect instead of just a simulation. For example, when the battery reaches 20% it starts to charge and when it reaches 90% it stops charging. Unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution.

Comment: Perhaps your best option is to buy a smart plug and maybe connect it to [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com).